# Concatenate Columns on Import (MySQL/phpmyadmin)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table with a basic structure...
column1, column2, column3.

When I upload to this table on phpmyadmin (or any other environment for that matter), I would like to be able to add a fourth column which is a concatenation of the three columns being uploaded.

Is there any way of creating a column which is the equivalent of `CONCAT(column1, column2, column3) as column4` so that each time I import to this table, column4 will be populated automatically?

I'm trying to avoid having to do this work before import or after, which I presume would require creating an additional table.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers, Ste

Comment: 1. Create column4 manually. 2. Create ON BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER, that will set NEW.column4 = CONCAT(OLD.column1, OLD.column2, OLD.column3)

Comment: **Dont concatenate these fields on your database**. If you want them concatenated do it in the query that gets the data or in PHP when presenting the data

Comment: It can be done with a trigger, but don't. It's a bad idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need to create a extra column in your database rather you can just do the same while displaying the data using a `SELECT` statement saying

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3,
CONCAT(column1, column2, column3) as column4
FROM table1;
```

Comment: +1000 Or do the concatenation in PHP when you present that data to a user

Comment: @RiggsFolly, but I got only +1 where is rest ... that's cheating .. LOL

Comment: LOL, if only it were possible!

Comment: Thanks @Rahul. I'll stick to doing this within the SELECT statement. Because it was an archive table and I was trying to make a unique_id using the concatenation, I was trying to make this column a permanent fixture in the table but there's no reason why I can't create it each time in the SELECT query. Thanks to all for advice.